# how to print even alphabet using numpy arrays with additional condition

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

    a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    a=np.array(a)
    b=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
    b=np.array(b)
    # conversion of both list to array
    # want to print even alphabets except 'b'
    print(b[a%2==0 and a!=2])
```

What is the problem with `and` condition and tell me how to rectify it?
Also I want to know to print only alternative even alphabets- ('d','h','l')

Comment: By alternative you mean every 4th one? Like `if not a%4: print b[a]`?

Answer (score 1):

The major problem in your code is:

`b[a%2==0 and a!=2]`

This throws a `ValueError`:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

And makes no sense in general (you are trying to access something of the sort of `b[True]` and applying to modulus (`%`) operator on an array...).
 I think what you were trying to do is print all the even numbers in `a`, which you can do with:

```
[a[index] for index, x in enumerate(a) if a[index] % 2 == 0]
```

**Edit:** Maybe I misread the question, because it is extremely unclear, but I think what you wanted is to print every 4th element of `b` except the actual element `b` which is in `index =` 1:

```
>>> [b[i-1] for i in a if i % 4 == 0 and i != 1]
['d', 'h', 'l']
```

Comment: In title and body , it says print alphabet. So most likely, it should be `b[something]` since `a` is there to create index like you do with enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

a=np.array(a)

b=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']

b=np.array(b)

print (list(b[i-1] for i in a if i%4==0 and i!=1))

Answer (score 1):

```py
import string
np.array([*string.ascii_lowercase])[np.arange(26)%2 == 0]
```

returns:

```
array(['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's', 'u', 'w', 'y'],
  dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to replace AND condition to print alphabets with even numerics:

```
print(b[(a%2==0) & (a!=2)])
```

Also for printing alternate even alphabets ('d','h','I')

I wouldn't write the code but the **logical implementation** would be simply:

print b(index a%4==0)

also to ignore printing 'd' :

print b(index a%4==0 & index a!=4)